# Pinvoke call to CeGetVolumeInfo requires an unknown enum value

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, pinvoke

I'm still fairly new to PInvoke calls, so I'm hoping that someone out there can help me clear this up:

I'm trying to PInvoke a call to CeGetVolumeInfo()- which is kept in CoreDll.dll- from a C# project.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912305.aspx) is the definition for this function from MSDN:

```
 WINBASEAPI BOOL CeGetVolumeInfo(  
 LPCWSTR pszRootPath,  
 CE_VOLUME_INFO_LEVEL InfoLevel,  
 LPCE_VOLUME_INFO lpVolumeInfo );
```

My problem is with the `CE_VOLUME_INFO_LEVEL` parameter.  I'm assuming it's an enum of some kind, but I can't figure out what its actual value is (MSDN provides NO value info for it), and googling it comes up with almost nothing.

Any suggestions on how to get/use the unknown value of an enum defined in a PInvoke reachable dll?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following link
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912305.aspx)

"InfoLevel
     [in] Type of information requested. Currently, this value must be set to CeVolumeInfoLevelStandard."

From the header storemgr.h

> typedef enum _CE_VOLUME_INFO_LEVEL {
>       CeVolumeInfoLevelStandard, } CE_VOLUME_INFO_LEVEL;

Comment: Actually I didn't answer the question. In C++ the default value for the first item in an enumeration is 0. You want to pass 0 for the value of CeVolumeInfoLevelStandard in your PINVOKE call.

Answer (score 0):

I *knew* it had to be something simple. I just completely glazed over that whole "header file" part...  Downloaded the Windows CE 5.0 sdk and now I'm straight.

Thanks again!